# jQuery - hide, show, add/remove class on dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I'm stuck with this project where I have dynamically injected some external HTML into my main document and I want to reference elements that are inside the external document. I'm aware of the `on()` method, which I have used and it works, but the actions inside the function are not working at all.

For some reference, the injected HTML code is a simple button which should hide another element when clicked. Like so:

```html
<! –– MAIN HTML––>
...
<div class="main">
</div>
...
```

```html
<! –– INJECTED HTML (content_home.html)––>

<button id="button">Button</button>
<div id="stuff">Stuff</div>
```

I wrote this in my JavaScript code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

const main = $(".main");

function loadHome() {
        fetch('html/content_home.html').then(function (response) {
            return response.text();
        }).then(function (html) {
            main.append(html);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.warn('Something went wrong.', error);
        });
}

loadHome();

const doc = $(document);

doc.on("click", "#button", function() {
  $('#stuff').hide();
  console.log("You clicked on the button.");
})
}
```

The thing is, the console displays the desired message when clicking the button, so I know something is working, but that's it. `hide()`, `show()` don't work at all. The console doesn't even throw an error.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to add a $(this) of sorts? I've been browsing the internet looking for the answer, to no avail.

Thank you

Comment: @pc_coder, please notice *the console displays the desired message when clicking the button*.

Comment: As others have stated, the code in this example works. If I were you, the first thing I would do is confirm that I do indeed have an element with `id="stuff"` in my DOM when I click the button. I would put a `console.log($("#stuff").length);` in my button click handler and confirm that it outputs `1`.

Answer (score 0):

your code is working correctly. maybe you have not linked jquery script correctly.

```js
const doc = $(document);

doc.on("click", "#button", function() {
        $('#stuff').toggle();
        console.log("You clicked on the button.");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Button</button>
<div id="stuff">Stuff</div>
```

Comment: *the console displays the desired message when clicking the button!!!*

Comment: but I have already imported it in the main HTML. Does it need to be imported into the injected HTML as well?

Comment: No you don't need it works so doc works and give console result. Problem is not in these codes.These ones works . Can you share your dynamic creatin code also ?

Comment: Hello, the code is working correctly may be there is another problem in your page that is blocking this. Here this snippet works correctly.